# vb.net data connection with mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, dataset

Recently i build a pos but the datagridview doesnt refresh i tried different methods but its not worikng

```
   Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into bazaartikli123.artikli(id,barkod,naziv,kupovna,prodazna,opis) values ('" & TextBoxBarkod.Text & "','" & TextBoxNaziv.Text & "','" & TextBoxKupovna.Text & "','" & TextBoxProdazna.Text & "','" & TextBoxOpis.Text & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konecija)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
          Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, konekcija)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()


        MessageBox.Show("Артиклот е успешно внесен !")
        TextBoxBarkod.Text = ""
        TextBoxKupovna.Text = ""
        TextBoxNaziv.Text = ""
        TextBoxOpis.Text = ""
        TextBoxProdazna.Text = ""
        dataadapter.Fill(ds)
        konecija.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "Artikli"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        konecija.Dispose()

    End Try
```

Bazadataset ,ArtikliBindingSource , ArtikliTableAdapter

Comment: here, you just insert in your database. you don't refresh your datagridview. To refresh it, we need to know how you bind your dtgv

Comment: i updated the queston

Comment: If you configure the DataAdapter correctly, `myDA,Update()` will refresh the rows.

Comment: can you tell me how the code should be i provided the dataset and adapters below